# Ploting a certain bar next to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have two bars, later on I would like to have 3, 4, 5 bars I would like to plot next to each other. For each bar plot there will be the some x-ticks but all of them as in the main plot but different y-ticks values. And I would like to plot them next to each other and not stacked.

My code example

```
y_ticks_1 = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'] 
x_ticks_1 = [2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 8.5]
y_ticks_2 = ['A1', 'A3', 'A4']
x_ticks_2 = [3.5, 6, 7.5]
#later on there will be more sets of data

width = 1
y_pos = arrange(len(y_ticks_1))
figure('bar', figsize=(11,5))
barh(y_ticks_1, x_ticks_1, align='edge', alpha=0.5)
barh(y_ticks_2, x_ticks_2, color='r', align='edge', alpha=0.5)
yticks(y_pos + width/2)
xlabel('yield (%)')
```

But when I do that it only changes the length of y-axis and the bars are still covering each other out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer your specific question for two sets of data. You can use a negative height to align the bars on either side of the ticks.

```
y_ticks_1 = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'] 
x_ticks_1 = [2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 8.5]
y_ticks_2 = ['A1', 'A3', 'A4']
x_ticks_2 = [3.5, 6, 7.5]

y_pos = np.arange(len(y_ticks_1)+1)
plt.figure('bar', figsize=(11,5))
plt.barh(y_ticks_1, x_ticks_1, align='edge', height=0.3, alpha=0.5)
plt.barh(y_ticks_2, x_ticks_2, color='r', height=-0.3, align='edge', alpha=0.5)
plt.yticks(y_pos)
plt.xlabel('yield (\%)')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I feel so stupid. I edited the plot as I don't have horizontal. Its been bugging me for 1 day now. Sorry for the basic question.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer: So is your problem solved? Or what else needs to be changed?

Comment: It is! I will check it as an answer as soon as I can :) thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didnt know they are different things I thought it was just answer and that was the best thing. You definitely deserve an upvote too